# How do you combining tables in access where field limit of 255 is passed?

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is there anyway of combining tables in access and the outputting them to excel when the results of the combine would be larger than the 255 field limit

Comment: You could use VBA to write data out to a CSV file and then open that file in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Consider breaking up the query below the 255-column limit into multiple queries (all same structure). Then, open the queries as VBA recordsets to be copied into an Excel workbook at specific range for contiguous output, specifically using the [CopyFromRecordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839240.aspx) method.

Below is a generalized Access VBA solution assuming two queries with 200 columns each. Adjust particulars as needed. Instead of named objects, you can use an SQL statement inside `OpenRecordset()`.

```
Dim xlApp As Object, xlWkb As object
Dim db As Database, rst1 As Recordset, rst2 As Recordset
Dim fld1 As Field, fld2 As Field
Dim i As Integer
Const xlOpenXMLWorkbook = 51

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst1 = db.OpenRecordset("query1", dbOpenDynaset)  ' FIRST 200 COLUMNS
Set rst2 = db.OpenRecordset("query2", dbOpenDynaset)  ' NEXT 200 COLUMNS

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks

' COLUMNS
i = 1
For Each fld1 in rst1.Fields
   xlWkb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, i) = fld1.Name
   i = i + 1
Next fld1

 ' DATA ROWS
xlWkb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rst1


' COLUMNS
i = 0
For Each fld2 in rst2.Fields
   xlWkb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 201 + i) = fld2.Name
   i = i + 1
Next fld2

 ' DATA ROWS
xlWkb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 201).CopyFromRecordset rst2

xlWkb.SaveAs "C:\Path\To\Workbook\AccessData.xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook
xlApp.Visible = True

rst1.Close: rst2.Close
Set rst1 = Nothing
Set rst2 = Nothing    
Set db = Nothing

Set xlWkb = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```